# Angular POS Print Issue

Tags: angular, rsvp.js, rsvp-promise

My requirement: Print without print preview angular 6

Only solution i found

[Angular 2 Raw Printing Service](https://medium.com/@yehandjoe/angular-2-raw-printing-service-56614d358754)
I am using think link for Angular POS print

**Do i have any other alternatives?**

.ts code

```
 printInvoice() {
  console.log(this.printService.getPrinters());
  }
```

My Service code

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as shajs from 'sha.js';
import * as qz from 'qz-tray';
**import * as RSVP from 'rsvp';**

@Injectable()
export class QzTrayService {
    constructor() { }

    errorHandler(error: any): Observable<any> {
        console.log('error handler');
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }

    // Get list of printers connected
    getPrinters(): Observable<string[]> {
        console.log(Observable
            .fromPromise(qz.websocket.connect()
                .then(() => qz.printers.find()))
            .map((printers: string[]) => printers) );
        return Observable
            .fromPromise(qz.websocket.connect()
            .then(() => qz.printers.find()))
            .map((printers: string[]) => printers)
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
    }

    // Get the SPECIFIC connected printer
    getPrinter(printerName: string): Observable<string> {
        return Observable
            .fromPromise(qz.websocket.connect().then(() => qz.printers.find(printerName)))
            .map((printer: string) => printer)
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
    }

    // Print data to chosen printer
    printData(printer: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
        // Create a default config for the found printer
        const config = qz.configs.create(printer);
        return Observable.fromPromise(qz.print(config, data))
            .map((anything: any) => anything)
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
    }

    // Disconnect QZ Tray from the browser
    removePrinter(): void {
        qz.websocket.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

I get RSVP is not defined, how to correct this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the code where you're calling `RSVP`?

Comment: this is my code.. i am not calling RSVP, i included RSVP in service imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding it in to that file will not make it available to other scripts.

You need to include it as a global script.

To do so, add the following into your index.html:

```
<head>
   <script src="../node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Alternately, you can include it in `angular.json` in the scripts section

Comment: but i am not getting list of printers